# Run .sh file as root to install it

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am new to ubuntu. I want to install a (.sh) file and I followed this tutorial [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTKv9PI4-x0), and it works great. but in the last thing before installing the file it gives me this message "**This script must be run as root**". I install the unlocker file to install mac in vmware. the file name is "**lnx-install.sh**".

**Here is a screenshot from my terminal**

[image]

Comment: Please try sudo ./lnx-install.sh

Comment: What you want depends on something: is the .sh created for UBUNTU or for another operating system? If Ubuntu you need to do what @nk_ commented. Otherwise you need to do `sudo -i`, provide the password (you get a `#` prompt), copy the .sh to /opt (that is the dir used for 3rd party installs) and dio ./lnx-install.sh`. The reason: it will preserve the permissions of the contents.

Comment: Oh it is probably this one: https://github.com/coolrepo99/unlocker/blob/master/lnx-install.sh

Comment: Thank you. I have tried what (NK_) said and it gives me this message "./lnx-install.sh: line 30: python2: command not found" so should now I install python?

Comment: No. You are now running into a problem: that script is intended for python2 and python2 has gone end of life. You need a script that is used for python3. Best option: open the script and change `python2 ./unlocker.py` to `python3 ./unlocker.py` and hope it works, If not you need to ask for a python3 version of `unlocker.py` ;) You should not be using software from 2015(!) on an 2021 operating system.

Comment: There is a much newer version of the same program at [https://github.com/BDisp/unlocker](https://github.com/BDisp/unlocker) - it does have specific instructions for handling python in linux